# I have a process (left) that I cannot kill? Anything aside from a reboot?

Tags: kill

I have a process that I ran under a Tmux session that I cannot kill.

I have tried kill, kill -9, a few other kill numbers, without it having any effect.

I killed the tmux session successfully but the process lives on.

It does not appear that it has any parents that I can find using different variations of ps.

I could use some help.

Comment: Is the job running as root? If so, are you trying to kill. If not, could you be more specific? (Did you start the file by its name in the command window, or did you click on an icon?)

Comment: run "systemctl | grep abandoned" and see if there are any abandoned process. If there are, run "systemctl stop session-cXXX.scope" where XXX is a number associate with the abandoned process, you will know right away what this value is if you have any of these processes. You may also need to run "systemctl stop username-YYYY.slice" if you have an abandoned session as sometimes happens with tmux.

Comment: I forgot to mention you will need to run the above commands as root